# How to loop through a huge XMLList without any lag?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have an xml list that contains around 50000 items.when i search something, i use a for loop to loop through all the elements.. It works but the app becomes unresponsive for about 4 seconds. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Please show your code. 50000 items are much. And 4 seconds seem to be a realistic time to search it. Maybe there are ways to prefilter the xml.

Comment: use E4X instead of loops, it has better performance

Answer (score 1):

If you only search it then you should use the XML search methods instead of looping through yourself.

For example this:

```
var searchResult:XMLList = xmlData.*.(NAME == "search");
searchResult = xmlData.*.(NAME == "search" || NAME == "other");//more example
searchResult = xmlData.*.(NAME == "search" && @type == "attribute");//more example
```

Returns all elements with a NAME tag with the content "search". You can look up attributes as well, etc ... You can write complex search logic and get results without any loops.

If you absolutely must loop then you need to break your loop into steps. Keep a iterator reference and set a max loop number, something like:

```
var iterator:int = 0;
var maxLoop:int = 1000;
var timer:Timer = etc ...
timer.start();
```

Now with each Timer tick you loop through the xml starting at "iterator" and ending at "maxLoop" you then increase "iterator" by maxLoop and run the second timer tick etc ... It won't make the overall loop faster but it will stop the app from idling. You can even display a progress bar.

EDIT: Deleting XMLList.

If you need to delete a XMLList then get its index and delete from its parent. Taking the example above and assuming only one element is returned (if more than one use a loop) and xmlData root is the parent of NAME XMLList:

```
var elementIndex:int = searchResult.childIndex();
delete xmlData.NAME[elementIndex];
```

Comment: another way to prevent blocking the UI would be to use a Worker.

Comment: Thanks alot.. The searching now works great but i am unable to delete the node having that specific attribute..